# mysterious "'str' object is not callable" python error

Tags: python-2.6

I am currently making my first python effort, a modification of some code written by a friend.  I am using python 2.6.6.  The original piece of code, which works, extracts information from a log file of data from donations made by credit card to my nonprofit.  My new version, should it one day work, will perform the same task for donations that were made by paypal.  The log files are similar, but have different field names and other differences.

---

The error messages I'm getting are:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../logparse-paypal-1.py", line 196, in 
    convert_log(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], access_ids)
  File "../logparse-paypal-1.py", line 170, in convert_log
    output = [f(record, access_ids) for f in output_fns]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I've read some of the posts on this forum related to this error message, but so far I'm still at sea.  I can't find any consequential differences between the portions of my code that related to the likely problem object (access_ids) and the code that I started with.  All I did related to the access_ids table was to remove some lines that printed problems the script finds with the table that caused it to ignore some data.  Perhaps I changed a character or something while doing that, but I've looked and so far can't find anything.

The portion of the code that is producing these error messages is the following:

```
            # Use the output functions configured above to convert the
            # transaction record into a list of outputs to be emitted to
            # the CSV output file.
            print "Converting %s at %s to CSV" % (record["type"], record["time"])
            output = [f(record, access_ids) for f in output_fns]
            j = 0
            while j < len(output):
                    os.write(csv_fd, output[j])
                    if j < len(output) - 1:
                            os.write(csv_fd, ",")
                    else:
                            os.write(csv_fd, "\n")
                    j += 1
            convert_count += 1

    print "Converted %d approved transactions to CSV format, skipped %d non-approved transactions" % (convert_count, skip_count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
            print "Usage: logparse.py INPUT_FILE OUTPUT_FILE [ACCESS_IDS_FILE]"
            print
            print "  INPUT_FILE        Silent post log containing transaction records (must exist)"
            print "  OUTPUT_FILE       Filename for the CSV file to be created (must not exist, will be created)"
            print "  ACCESS_IDS_FILE   List of Access IDs and email addresses (optional, must exist if specified)"
            sys.exit(-1)

    access_ids = {}
    if len(sys.argv) > 3:
            access_ids = load_access_ids(sys.argv[3])

    convert_log(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], access_ids)
```

Line 170 is this one:
output = [f(record, access_ids) for f in output_fns]

and line 196 is this one:
convert_log(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], access_ids)

---

The access_ids definition, possibly related to the problem, is this:

```
def access_id_fn(record, access_ids):
        if "payer_email" in record and len(record["payer_email"]) > 0:
                if record["payer_email"] in access_ids:
                        return '"' + access_ids[record["payer_email"]] + '"'
                else:
                        return ""
        else:
                return ""
```

AND

```
def load_access_ids(filename):
        print "Loading Access IDs from %s..." % filename
        access_ids = {}
        for line in open(filename, "r"):
                line = line.rstrip()
                access_id, email = [s.strip() for s in line.split(None, 1)]
                if not email_address.match(email):
                        continue
                if email in access_ids:
                        access_ids[string.strip(email)] = string.strip(access_id)
        return access_ids
```

Thanks in advance for any advice with this.

- Dave

Comment: Can you post a [*complete*](http://sscce.org/#selfcon) test program that shows the problem? Most likely, the value of `output_fn` is the problem.

Comment: I think you problem is that output_fns is a list of strings. So in the context of the list comprehension statement, f() is not a function, but is instead a string. Try adding the following print statement just before line 170 "print '%s' % output_fns"

Comment: @user590028, I added that line.  Here is the message I get now:

  File "../logparse-paypal-1.py", line 170, in convert_log
    print '%s' % output_fns
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @phihag, how do I get past the character limit in the comment box?  Should I just post the whole program as a new question?

Comment: @DavidBorden You should post a [complete example](http://sscce.org/#selfcon). If your current code is over, say, 30 lines, simplify it drastically until you either don't get the error (then undo one simplification step) or you get a short program that shows the error.

Comment: @phihag I've been able to reduce it to 87 lines -- and unfortunately it works, and I don't know why.  :)  But I'll look again later.  You've given me additional debugging ideas too.

Comment: Thank you to all of you for the help.  I had a syntax error on one line in particular, due to my inexperience with python, and I was able to narrow it down by deleting various lines from a section of the script and then adding them back gradually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything right off hand, but you did mention that the log files were similar and I take that to mean that there are differences between the two.

Can you post a line from each?

I would double check the data in the log files and make sure what you think is being read in is correct. This definitely appears to me like a piece of data is being read in, but somewhere it is breaking what the code is expecting.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  One of the files being read in is the same for both, the one that gets read into the access_ids array.  Here is a sample line:

59337   1@1.COM

Here are some lines from the log file that is getting read correctly in the first version of this script:

Network Donation
2013-07-01T04:03:15-05:00
x_response_code: 3
x_response_reason_code: 8
x_response_reason_text: The credit card has expired.
x_avs_code: P
x_auth_code: 

and here are some lines from the newer log file:

Network Donation
2013-07-10T18:16:16-05:00
mc_gross: 1.00
protection_eligibility: Eligible